# Which sentence is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, translation, english-to-japanese, hiragana

I'm unsure how to write the sentence "That (near you) is a pencil." in Japanese.
Is it "Sono pen wa desu." or "Sore wa pen desu." ? Or are both of them right/wrong? 
I'm a beginner so I can only read and write in hiragana at the moment (haven't started with kanji and katakana yet).

Apreciate your help!

Comment: Well, ペン (pen) doesn't mean pencil, firstly...

Answer (score 1):

> それはえんぴつです。

Means "That is a pencil." The other sentence is ungrammatical, but you could make it grammatical by adding a word, such as:

> その[ペン]{ぺん}は**あかい**です。

"That pen is red."

Comment: 英語の "That pen is red." って、「そのペンは赤です・それは赤ペンです」って意味？ それとも「そのペンは赤いです。」(←見た目が赤い)って意味？それとも両方アリ？

Comment: @Chocolate Just saying 'the pen is red' in English is ambiguous. The meaning would come from context, but I think most of the time it would refer to the ink colour.

Comment: おお～ ありがとうございます ＾＾ @user3856370

Answer (score 0):

"Sono pen wa desu" breaks down for 2 reasons, one grammatical, one logical:

- 'desu' needs a predicate (see mamster's example): for mere existence you need 'arimasu'.
- As soon as you write "sono pen" you take it for granted that it's a pen, just as in English you cannot start a question with 'this pen' to ask whether it's a pen.